# Using reduceLeft in place of foldLeft in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, fold

I wanted to ensure if I could accomplish this by using **reduceLeft** rather than **foldLeft**. I am searching a given number in the List

```
val included = List(46, 19, 92).foldLeft(false) { (a, i) =>
| if (a) a else (i == 19)
| }
included: Boolean = true
```

However I want to accomplish the same using **reduceLeft**, is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly. The types, as is often the case, are the answer.

reduceLeft has a type sort of like:

```
List[A] => ((A,A) => A) => A
```

Given a List of A, and a function which can combine 2 A values into 1 A value, you get a single A value back.

what you could do would be something like:

```
val a = List(46, 19, 92).reduceLeft { (a, b) =>
 if(b == 19) b else a
}

val included = a == 19
```

Of course, you'd be better served using "contains" for this than either of those options.

Comment: `contains`, not `exists`, `list contains 19` vs `list exists (_ == 19)`

Comment: Correct, and fixed, that's what I get for writing answers when I'm on mobile :).

Answer (score 5):

The proper way to do this is

```
val included = List(46, 19, 92).contains(19)
```

But if you would insist on using `reduceLeft`, then you can write:

```
val included = List(46, 19, 92).reduceLeft { (a, b) =>
  if (b == 19) b else a
} == 19
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in a simple way. With foldLeft you can define the result type : it's the type of your accumulator so i's the type of the zero element you give as first parameter.
ReduceLeft uses the first element of your collection as the zero element of your accumulator. So the result type will be the same as the elements of the list, Int in your case.